# Copying data entry values in to a separate WorkFile

Tags: vba, excel

The code is working but slow. Is there a way to speed it up or make it more compact but still easy to read?

There are 35 different jobs to be done. They are made in a worksheet with merged cells to enter, who did the job, when, how long, workorder, nr, etc. Next to the layout is a command button, and when you click on it, it will copy all the values to a list in another WorkFile.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
GetBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Call OpenFile
Call ReadOnly
Call FindLastRow

Set rng = Worksheets("PHASE").Range("N13:O16")

With CommandButton2
    .Caption = "Is al Ingegeven"
    .Left = rng.Left
    .Top = rng.Top
    .Width = rng.Width
    .Height = rng.Height
    .WordWrap = True

End With

        'Tail Nummer
    Windows(GetBook).Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    Call CopyTailNum

        'Datum
    Windows(GetBook).Activate
    Range("B14").Select
    Call CopyDate

        'Naam
    Windows(GetBook).Activate
    Range("B16").Select
    Call CopyNaam

        'Werk
    Windows(GetBook).Activate
    Range("A13").Select
    Call CopyWerk

        'Start Uur
    Windows(GetBook).Activate
    Range("E14").Select
    Call CopyStartUur

        'Eind Uur
    Windows(GetBook).Activate
    Range("E15").Select
    Call CopyEindUur

        'Remarks
    Windows(GetBook).Activate
    Range("H16").Select
    Call CopyRemarks

        'WOnr
    Windows(GetBook).Activate
    Range("K13").Select
    Call CopyWONr

Call UpdateTable
Workbooks("StartBlad.xlsm").Save
Windows(GetBook).Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Call UpdateMessage

End Sub
```

Here is the second command button:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
GetBook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Call OpenFile
Call ReadOnly
Call FindLastRow
Set rng = Worksheets("PHASE").Range("N18:O21")

With CommandButton3
    .Caption = "Is al Ingegeven"
    .Left = rng.Left
    .Top = rng.Top
    .Width = rng.Width
    .Height = rng.Height
    .WordWrap = True

End With

        'Tail Nummer
    Windows(GetBook).Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    Call CopyTailNum

        'Datum
    Windows(GetBook).Activate
    Range("B19").Select
    Call CopyDate

        'Naam
    Windows(GetBook).Activate
    Range("B21").Select
    Call CopyNaam

        'Werk
    Windows(GetBook).Activate
    Range("A18").Select
    Call CopyWerk

        'Start Uur
    Windows(GetBook).Activate
    Range("E19").Select
    Call CopyStartUur

        'Eind Uur
    Windows(GetBook).Activate
    Range("E20").Select
    Call CopyEindUur

        'Remarks
    Windows(GetBook).Activate
    Range("H21").Select
    Call CopyRemarks

        'WOnr
    Windows(GetBook).Activate
    Range("K18").Select
    Call CopyWONr

Call UpdateTable
Workbooks("StartBlad.xlsm").Save
Windows(GetBook).Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Call UpdateMessage

End Sub
```

If you can see, the difference between the 2 buttons is the placement and the Range.
I have 35 buttons.

Here are the subs that are called.

```
Sub CopyTailNum()
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("StartBlad.xlsm").Activate
    Worksheets("WorkFile").Range("A" & LastRow + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub

Sub CopyDate()
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("StartBlad.xlsm").Activate
    Worksheets("WorkFile").Range("B" & LastRow + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone,     SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub

Sub CopyNaam()
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("StartBlad.xlsm").Activate
    Worksheets("WorkFile").Range("C" & LastRow + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub

Sub CopyWerk()
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("StartBlad.xlsm").Activate
    Worksheets("WorkFile").Range("D" & LastRow + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub

Sub CopyStartUur()
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("StartBlad.xlsm").Activate
    Worksheets("WorkFile").Range("E" & LastRow + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub

Sub CopyEindUur()
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("StartBlad.xlsm").Activate
    Worksheets("WorkFile").Range("F" & LastRow + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub

Sub CopyRemarks()
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("StartBlad.xlsm").Activate
    Worksheets("WorkFile").Range("G" & LastRow + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub

Sub CopyWONr()
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("StartBlad.xlsm").Activate
    Worksheets("WorkFile").Range("H" & LastRow + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub

Function WorkbookOpen(WorkBookName As String) As Boolean
WorkbookOpen = False
On Error GoTo WorkBookNotOpen
If Len(Application.Workbooks(WorkBookName).Name) > 0 Then
    WorkbookOpen = True
    Exit Function
End If
WorkBookNotOpen:
End Function

Sub OpenFile()
Dim File As String
Dim wkBk As Workbook
File = Worksheets("PHASE").Range("W1") & "\" & "StartBlad.xlsm"

If WorkbookOpen("StartBlad.xlsm") Then
'    Workbooks("StartBlad.xlsm").Activate
Else: Workbooks.Open (File)
End If

End Sub

Sub ReadOnly()
    If ActiveWorkbook.ReadOnly Then
        MsgBox ("!!! STARTBLAD IS READ-ONLY. GEEN GEGEVENS DOORGEVOERD !!!")
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
        End

    End If
End Sub

Sub FindLastRow()
Workbooks("StartBlad.xlsm").Activate
Worksheets("WorkFile").Activate
With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
End Sub

Sub UpdateTable()
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("WorkFileTable").Resize Range("$A$1:$H$" & LastRow + 1)
End Sub
```

If needed I can link the complete excel file.

Comment: This can be improved quite a bit

Comment: If you can redact the Excel workbook and provide a link to public DropBox or GoogleDrive link (One Drive won't allow macro-driven files and I do not want to sign up for anyone's service) it would answer a few questions I had.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I noticed about the posted code was that it was very easy to follow.

A structure that allowed to identify elements, flow, and more importantly, patterns

One note about indentation: all code in a Sub() or Function() should be indented one level, and the inner blocks should have increased levels of indentation accordingly

The next obvious thing I noticed was the use of `.Activate` and `.Select` which triggered inefficiency warnings: `.Select` is never needed and it's the slowest of the two, `.Activate` might be needed on very rare occasions but for most operations it's not, so these would be the first improvements to be applied to more than 90% of the code

Another inefficiency is to re-position the command buttons at every click. The positional anchor (range) is always the same so they're basically static, but if you need to make sure they have a consistent position it would be reasonable to reset them once, when the file first opens. The only reason for buttons to move is if a user goes into Design Mode and drags them somewhere else (not likely in normal usage)

Related to code size, the two Click() subs have an identical structure except for the ranges. You don't need to extract `ActiveWorkbook.Name` with every click, so this can be moved to the `Workbook_Open()` event where a limited set of global variables can keep a reference to the two working files and their main worksheets

The most generic code usually doesn't have ANY hard-coded values: all references to ranges, file names and paths, messages (all strings in general), and all numeric values should be defined as constants, within the most limited scope (private to the block, Sub \ Function, or Module level). Hard-coded values are causing most of the unnecessary maintenance effort, especially when the same values are used in multiple places

You are using `Application.ScreenUpdating` well - turn it off before, then back on. You should keep in mind though, that if the code errors out at any point in between, users will be confused when Excel doesn't refresh the screen properly because it wasn't able to turn this setting back on.

The repetitive and unnecessary processing continues in both Click() events:

```
Call OpenFile
Call ReadOnly

Set rng = Worksheets("PHASE").Range("N13:O16")
```

1. Check if the file is open (every click)
2. Check if the file is read-only (every click)
3. Set `rng` to Worksheets("PHASE").Range("N13:O16") (every click)

All these calls can be moved to the one-time processing of `Workbook_Open()`

```
Call UpdateTable
```

"WorkFileTable" in StartBlad.xlsm file doesn't need to be re-sized: you first determine the last row, then copy the new values into the previous range, without adding or removing rows

Combining the items above you would get the click events similar to this:

```
Private Sub Update1()  'CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim lastCell As Range, lastRow As Long

    lastRow = GetMaxCell(wsWorkFile).Row

    If lastRow > 1 Then

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        With wsPhase

            CopyData .Range(TAIL_NUMMER_1), wsWorkFile.Range("A" & lastRow + 1)
            CopyData .Range(DATUM_1), wsWorkFile.Range("B" & lastRow + 1)
            CopyData .Range(NAAM_1), wsWorkFile.Range("C" & lastRow + 1)
            CopyData .Range(WERK_1), wsWorkFile.Range("D" & lastRow + 1)
            CopyData .Range(START_UUR_1), wsWorkFile.Range("E" & lastRow + 1)
            CopyData .Range(EIND_UUR_1), wsWorkFile.Range("F" & lastRow + 1)
            CopyData .Range(REMARKS_1), wsWorkFile.Range("G" & lastRow + 1)
            CopyData .Range(WONR_1), wsWorkFile.Range("H" & lastRow + 1)

        End With

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        'Call UpdateMessage  'this is missing from initial code...

    End If

End Sub
```

(I'm not sure what `UpdateMessage` is)

Moving to the called subs section, all Copy*() subs are identical and can be combined into one sub that takes 2 parameters - copyFrom and copyTo as ranges

```
Sub CopyData(ByRef fromRange As Range, ByRef toRange As Range)
    toRange.Value2 = fromRange.Value2
End Sub
```

The following actions have been replaced by a direct copy of values:

- .Copy
- .Activate
- .Select
- .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

(probably this is where most processing time was spent)

All Subs() and Functions should be explicitly defined as Public or Private, to show your intent. Excel defaults to Public scope and that's bad coding practice - it should default to Private but this would confuse inexperienced programmers, so in a way is a more forgiving behavior intended not to discourage or overwhelm

The last note is about Function `WorkbookOpen`. It relies on expected errors instead of properly detecting if the file is open or not:

```
Public Function getWorkBook(ByVal wbName As String) As Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If wb.Name = wbName Then
            Set getWorkBook = wb
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

If the above returns nothing the file is not open - no need to trigger errors

---

This is how I would setup the code:

---

New user module: `modActions`:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Update1()  'CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim lastCell As Range, lastRow As Long
    lastRow = GetMaxCell(wsWorkFile).Row
    If lastRow > 1 Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        With wsPhase
            CopyData .Range(TAIL_NUMMER_1), wsWorkFile.Range("A" & lastRow + 1)
            CopyData .Range(DATUM_1), wsWorkFile.Range("B" & lastRow + 1)
            CopyData .Range(NAAM_1), wsWorkFile.Range("C" & lastRow + 1)
            CopyData .Range(WERK_1), wsWorkFile.Range("D" & lastRow + 1)
            CopyData .Range(START_UUR_1), wsWorkFile.Range("E" & lastRow + 1)
            CopyData .Range(EIND_UUR_1), wsWorkFile.Range("F" & lastRow + 1)
            CopyData .Range(REMARKS_1), wsWorkFile.Range("G" & lastRow + 1)
            CopyData .Range(WONR_1), wsWorkFile.Range("H" & lastRow + 1)
        End With
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub Update2()  'CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim lastCell As Range, lastRow As Long
    lastRow = GetMaxCell(wsWorkFile).Row
    If lastRow > 1 Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        With wsPhase
            CopyData .Range(TAIL_NUMMER_2), wsWorkFile.Range("A" & lastRow + 1)
            CopyData .Range(DATUM_2), wsWorkFile.Range("B" & lastRow + 1)
            CopyData .Range(NAAM_2), wsWorkFile.Range("C" & lastRow + 1)
            CopyData .Range(WERK_2), wsWorkFile.Range("D" & lastRow + 1)
            CopyData .Range(START_UUR_2), wsWorkFile.Range("E" & lastRow + 1)
            CopyData .Range(EIND_UUR_2), wsWorkFile.Range("F" & lastRow + 1)
            CopyData .Range(REMARKS_2), wsWorkFile.Range("G" & lastRow + 1)
            CopyData .Range(WONR_2), wsWorkFile.Range("H" & lastRow + 1)
        End With
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

---

New user module `modShared`:

```
Option Explicit

Public Const PATH_DELIM    As String = "\"
Public Const WB_PATH       As String = "W1"
Public Const WS_PHASE      As String = "PHASE"
Public Const WB_StartBlad  As String = "StartBlad.xlsm"
Public Const WS_WorkFile   As String = "WorkFile"

Public Const BTN_CAPTION   As String = "Is al Ingegeven"
Public Const READ_ONLY     As String = "!!! STARTBLAD IS READ-ONLY. GEEN GEGEVENS !!!"
Public Const INVALID_FILE  As String = "!!! File " & WB_StartBlad & " not found !!!"

Public Const BTN_RNG_1     As String = "N13:O16"
Public Const TAIL_NUMMER_1 As String = "A1"
Public Const DATUM_1       As String = "B14"
Public Const NAAM_1        As String = "B16"
Public Const WERK_1        As String = "A13"
Public Const START_UUR_1   As String = "E14"
Public Const EIND_UUR_1    As String = "E15"
Public Const REMARKS_1     As String = "H16"
Public Const WONR_1        As String = "K13"

Public Const BTN_RNG_2     As String = "N18:O21"
Public Const TAIL_NUMMER_2 As String = "A1"
Public Const DATUM_2       As String = "B19"
Public Const NAAM_2        As String = "B21"
Public Const WERK_2        As String = "A18"
Public Const START_UUR_2   As String = "E19"
Public Const EIND_UUR_2    As String = "E20"
Public Const REMARKS_2     As String = "H21"
Public Const WONR_2        As String = "K18"

Public Const WORKFILETABLE As String = "WorkFileTable"

Public thisWB       As Workbook
Public wsPhase      As Worksheet
Public thisWBName   As String

Public wbStartBlad  As Workbook
Public wsWorkFile   As Worksheet

Public Function getWorkBook(ByVal wbName As String) As Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If wb.Name = wbName Then
            Set getWorkBook = wb
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function

Public Sub RepositionButton(ByRef btn As MSForms.CommandButton, ByRef rng As Range)
    With btn
        .Caption = BTN_CAPTION
        .Left = rng.Left
        .Top = rng.Top
        .Width = rng.Width
        .Height = rng.Height
        .WordWrap = True
    End With
End Sub

Sub CopyData(ByRef fromRange As Range, ByRef toRange As Range)
    toRange.Value2 = fromRange.Value2
End Sub

'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Public Function GetMaxCell(Optional ByRef rng As Range = Nothing) As Range

    'It returns the last cell of range with data, or A1 if Worksheet is empty

    Const NONEMPTY As String = "*"
    Dim lRow As Range, lCol As Range

    If rng Is Nothing Then Set rng = Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) = 0 Then
        Set GetMaxCell = rng.Parent.Cells(1, 1)
    Else
        With rng
            Set lRow = .Cells.Find(What:=NONEMPTY, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                   After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                                   SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                   SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
            Set lCol = .Cells.Find(What:=NONEMPTY, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                   After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                                   SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                   SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
            Set GetMaxCell = .Parent.Cells(lRow.Row, lCol.Column)
        End With
    End If
End Function
```

---

`ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    setGlobals
End Sub
Public Sub setGlobals()
    Set thisWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsPhase = thisWB.Worksheets(WS_PHASE)
    thisWBName = thisWB.Name
    isReadOnly thisWB

    'Attempt to open WB_StartBlad
    Set wbStartBlad = getWorkBook(WB_StartBlad)

    If wbStartBlad Is Nothing Then
        Set wbStartBlad = Workbooks.Open( _
                                    wsPhase.Range(WB_PATH) & PATH_DELIM & WB_StartBlad)
        If wbStartBlad Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox INVALID_FILE
            thisWB.Close
        End If
    End If

    'Both files are now open
    Set wsWorkFile = wbStartBlad.Worksheets(WS_WorkFile)
    With thisWB.Worksheets(WS_PHASE)
        RepositionButton .CommandButton2, .Range(BTN_RNG_1)
        RepositionButton .CommandButton3, .Range(BTN_RNG_2)
    End With
End Sub

Private Function isReadOnly(ByRef wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    isReadOnly = wb.ReadOnly
    If isReadOnly Then
        MsgBox READ_ONLY
        wb.Close
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Wow oki thx a lot for the information. It helped me a lot to see what could be beter to this "program". I made this using google because I have no skills in VBA. It was my first attempt to do something like that just to help out my co-workers. I will make some changes to it. Still looking to find a way to avoid hardcoding cell ranges so it will be more easy to modify the code if they add or remove columns.  But again thx a lot for your time and information

Answer (score 2):

**Revisions**

> 1. Consolidate the common strings to public constants.
> 2. Remove dependency from the [Range .Activate method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221681(v=office.11).aspx) and *Selection* in the utility subs.
> 3. Parameterize the subs for versatility. Many subs are currently copies of each other with minor hard-coded differfences. Consolidate the various field copying to a single sub by passing in the column. Change sub(s) returning values to functions.
> 4. Change clipboard-driven Copy, Paste Special, Values to direct value transfer.
> 5. Make better use of the [ListObject properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn300900.aspx) available for explicit determination of operation targets.
> 6. Store 8 values in variant array and transfer to list object table as a row.

**Module1** (CommandButton2_Click & CommandButton3_Click)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim rng As Range, v As Long, vROW As Variant
    Dim sAWS As String, sAWB As String, aws As Worksheet

    'set up error handling then application environment
    On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
    appTGGL bTGGL:=False

    sAWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    sAWS = ActiveSheet.Name
    Set aws = ActiveSheet

    Call OpenFile

    Set rng = Worksheets("PHASE").Range("N13:O16") '<-not really sure what the parent workbook is

    With CommandButton2
        .Caption = "Is al Ingegeven"
        .Left = rng.Left
        .Top = rng.Top
        .Width = rng.Width
        .Height = rng.Height
        .WordWrap = True
    End With

    vROW = Array(aws.Range("A1").Value, aws.Range("B14").Value, _
                 aws.Range("B16").Value, aws.Range("A13").Value, _
                 aws.Range("E14").Value, aws.Range("E15").Value, _
                 aws.Range("H16").Value, aws.Range("K13").Value)
                'Tail Nummer Windows(GetBook).Range("A1")
                'Datum Windows(GetBook).Range("B14")
                'Naam Windows(GetBook).Range("B16")
                'Werk Windows(GetBook)Range("A13")
                'Start Uur Windows(GetBook).Range("E14")
                'Eind Uur Windows(GetBook)Range("E15")
                'Remarks Windows(GetBook).Range("H16")
                'WOnr Windows(GetBook).Range("K13")
    Call copyArrToWorkfileTbl(vVALs:=vROW)

    Call UpdateTable
    Workbooks(csSTARTBLADwb).Save
    Windows(sAWB).Activate

    'Call UpdateMessage  '<-couldn't find this sub

bm_Safe_Exit:
    appTGGL
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim rng As Range, v As Long, vROW As Variant
    Dim sAWS As String, sAWB As String, aws As Worksheet

    'set up error handling then application environment
    On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
    appTGGL bTGGL:=False

    sAWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    sAWS = ActiveSheet.Name
    Set aws = ActiveSheet

    Call OpenFile

    Set rng = Worksheets("PHASE").Range("N18:O21") '<-not really sure what the parent workbook is

    With CommandButton3
        .Caption = "Is al Ingegeven"
        .Left = rng.Left
        .Top = rng.Top
        .Width = rng.Width
        .Height = rng.Height
        .WordWrap = True
    End With

    vROW = Array(aws.Range("A1").Value, aws.Range("B19").Value, _
                 aws.Range("B21").Value, aws.Range("A18").Value, _
                 aws.Range("E19").Value, aws.Range("E20").Value, _
                 aws.Range("H21").Value, aws.Range("K18").Value)
                'Tail Nummer Windows(GetBook).Range("A1")
                'Datum Windows(GetBook).Range("B19")
                'Naam Windows(GetBook).Range("B21")
                'Werk Windows(GetBook).Range("A18")
                'Start Uur Windows(GetBook).Range("E19")
                'Eind Uur Windows(GetBook).Range("E20")
                'Remarks Windows(GetBook).Range("H21")
                'WOnr Windows(GetBook).Range("K18")
    Call copyArrToWorkfileTbl(vVALs:=vROW)

    Call UpdateTable
    Workbooks(csSTARTBLADwb).Save
    Windows(sAWB).Activate

    'Call UpdateMessage  '<-couldn't find this sub

bm_Safe_Exit:
    appTGGL
End Sub
```

**Module2** (public constants and utility subs/functions)

```
Option Explicit

Public Const csSTARTBLADwb As String = "StartBlad.xlsm"
Public Const csWORKFILEws As String = "WorkFile"
Public Const csWORKFILEtbl As String = "WorkFileTable"
Public Const csTAILNUMhdr As String = "Tail Nummer"

Sub copyValToWorkfileTbl(rng As Range, Optional hdr As String = csTAILNUMhdr)
    Dim iHDR As Long, iNR As Long

    With Workbooks(csSTARTBLADwb).Worksheets(csWORKFILEws)
        iHDR = Application.Match(hdr, .ListObjects(csWORKFILEtbl).HeaderRowRange, 0)
        iNR = FindLastRow(iCOL:=iHDR) + 1
        .Cells(iNR, iHDR) = rng.Value2
    End With

End Sub

Sub copyArrToWorkfileTbl(vVALs As Variant)
    Dim iHDR As Long, iNR As Long

    With Workbooks(csSTARTBLADwb).Worksheets(csWORKFILEws)
        iHDR = 1
        iNR = FindLastRow(iCOL:=iHDR) + 1
        .Cells(iNR, iHDR).Resize(1, UBound(vVALs) + 1) = vVALs
    End With

End Sub

Sub OpenFile()
    Dim fn As String, wb As Workbook

    fn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PHASE").Range("W1") & Chr(92) & csSTARTBLADwb

    If Not isWorkbookOpen(csSTARTBLADwb) Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fn, ReadOnly:=False, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True)
    End If

    Call isReadOnly(wb)

End Sub

Sub isReadOnly(Optional wb As Workbook)
    If wb Is Nothing Then _
        Set wb = Workbooks(csSTARTBLADwb)
    If wb.ReadOnly Then
        MsgBox ("!!! STARTBLAD IS READ-ONLY. GEEN GEGEVENS DOORGEVOERD !!!")
        wb.Close
        End
    End If
End Sub

Sub UpdateTable(Optional lo As ListObject)
    Dim nlr As Long
    If lo Is Nothing Then _
        Set lo = Workbooks(csSTARTBLADwb).Worksheets(csWORKFILEws).ListObjects(csWORKFILEtbl)

    nlr = FindLastRow + 1
    Debug.Print nlr
    With lo
        Debug.Print .Parent.Name
        .Resize .Parent.Range("A1:H" & nlr)
    End With
End Sub

Sub appTGGL(Optional bTGGL As Boolean = True)
    Application.EnableEvents = bTGGL
    Application.ScreenUpdating = bTGGL
    Application.DisplayAlerts = bTGGL
    Application.Cursor = IIf(bTGGL, xlDefault, xlWait)
    Application.Calculation = IIf(bTGGL, xlCalculationAutomatic, xlCalculationManual)
End Sub

Function isWorkbookOpen(WorkBookName As String) As Boolean
    isWorkbookOpen = False
    On Error GoTo WorkBookNotOpen
    If Len(Application.Workbooks(WorkBookName).Name) > 0 Then
        isWorkbookOpen = True
        Exit Function
    End If
WorkBookNotOpen:
    'not open - return false
End Function

Function FindLastRow(Optional ws As Worksheet, Optional iCOL As Long = 1)
    If ws Is Nothing Then _
        Set ws = Workbooks(csSTARTBLADwb).Worksheets(csWORKFILEws)

    With ws
        FindLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, iCOL).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Set ws = Nothing
End Function
```

There is a big question as to what workbook is the parent of the PHASE worksheet. It seemed to be ThisWorkbook but it was also implicitly referenced immediately after opening the StartBlad.xlsm which suggests that the StartBlad workbook is the parent. That needs to be decided and coded properly.

Answer (score 1):

**Before you do anything else**. Go to Tools--> Options --> Require variable Declaration.

That will automatically insert `Option Explicit` at the top of all modules. This is **incredibly** important because implicitly declared variables (especially those caused by inadvertent typos) will cause you no end of grief.